# Android AutoCompleteTextview Dropdown allow the user to select only

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In my android application, I'm using an `AutoCompleteTextview` on which the user has to select a name. If the user has entered some text (assume that the user didn't select text from `AutoCompleteTextview`), it also be displayed.

So, now I want to allow the user to only select the text and don't allow to enter the text. I've used

```
r_code.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            r_code.showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This code will display all the all the names when the user touches the `AutoCompleteTextview`. But it allows the user to enter some text. As mentioned above, I don't want to allow the user to enter text, they have to select the text. Can someone say how to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

I did basically the same as you.

1) I set the `OnTouchListener` to consume the click, so the view is not focused and the keyboard is not shown.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()
                return true
            }
        })
```

2) I added two things to my xml.

I set `focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`. This way the Keyboard is no longer shown, when the user clicks on the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        style="@style/Atomic.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Only downside here is that it won't be focused by `imeOptions="actionNext"`and therefore be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

check entered string with strings in arrayadapter if array does not contains entered string ask user to select another string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the selections to a known list, you can use a `Spinner`, see the [Spinners guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

add KeyListener r_code.setKeyListener and handle keys clicked. I think if you return true the key will be consumed.